# Insert Update and delete source flag records in target using informatica

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I implemented mapping same as below. can someone suggest that is the good approach or not.

old records copied from production so they didn't provide flag for those records. only new records we will get flag.

Source data:

```
col1   col2 col3  DML_FLAG
1      a    123   NULL(old record)
2      b    456   I
3      c    678   U
```

Mapping:

```
Source...>SQ...>exp...>lkp(on target to identify new or update)
       ..>exp..>...>RTR(for insert and update)-->upd(for update)...>target
```

First time load I have to load all records i.e full load(old records (DML_flag is null) and new records

From 2nd run I have to capture only changed records from source.For this I am using mapping variables

Here I have a question like, we have already I and U flags are available in source again I am using LKP,with out lookup, I can use DML_FLAG with two groups I and U in RTR.

But I need to refresh the data in every 30mints,with in 30 mints one record inserted(I) and same record got updated then flag changed to 'U' in the source, same record not available in the target, in that case can how can I capture that new record with flag 'U' without lkp.

can someone suggest how can I do this without lookup?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you want to make sure you apply the insert in your target before you apply the update to that same record - is this correct? If so the just use a target load plan having inserts routed to separate alias of same target and higher up in the load order than updates

The answer to whether this is correct as a design choice depends on what the target db is... for a datawarehouse fact table you would usually insert all records be they inserts or updates because you would be reporting on the event rather than the record state. For a dimension table it would depend on your slow changing dimension strategy

Comment: Thanks Daniel, yes I need to insert the record which is having flag as 'U' I need to refresh the data in every 30mints,with in 30 mints one record inserted(I) and same record got updated then flag changed to 'U' in the source, same record not available in the target.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the record to already be in the target unless you're doing an update. If that is the case then use target load plan as mentioned which will process all the inserts first and then the record will be there when it comes time to do the update.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, The record is not there in target. my source flow is Source     ETL  Target  
     Run 3(8:00)   
EMP No Name Location Flag Timestamp  EMP No Name Location
5 John CA I 6/11/2018 7:30 INSERT(I) 4 John NJ
5 John NJ U 6/11/2018 7:31 UPDATE(U)If a record got INSERTED and same record got UPDATED with in next refresh then ETL capture only UPDATED record and Insert into Target

Comment: Ok... if you want to only insert the update record the you can achieve this by using a sorter based on the shared key from the two records and the flag ascending. Followed by an aggregator on just the shared key and voila the record stamped with update comes through while the insert is filtered at the aggregator. Let me know if this matches your requirement